# How can I iterate over an 1D array and build a 2D array in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, loops, multidimensional-array

If I have an 1D `numpy.ndarray` `b` and a Python `function` `f` that I want to vectorize, this is very easy using the `numpy.vectorize` function:

`c = numpy.vectorize(f)(a)`.

But if `f` returns a 1D `numpy.ndarray` instead of a scalar, how can I build a 2D `numpy.ndarray` instead? (That is, I want every 1D `numpy.ndarray` returned from `f` to become a row in the new 2D `numpy.ndarray`.)

Example:

```
def f(x):
    return x * x

a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
c = numpy.vectorize(f)(a)

def f_1d(x):
    return numpy.array([x, x])

a = numpy.ndarray([1,2,3])
d = ???(f_1d)(a)
```

In the above example `c` would become `array([1, 4, 9])`. What should `???` be replaced with if `d` should become `array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])`?

Comment: You could also use the Kronecker product to do this without using a user defined function at all: `d=np.kron(np.ones((1,2),dtype=np.int), a.reshape((-1,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do this instead:

```
def f_1d(x):
    return (x,x)
d = numpy.column_stack(numpy.vectorize(f_1d)(a))
```

will output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: I tried that, but the `numpy.vectorize(f_1d)(a)` part throws `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`.

Comment: Replace your definition of `f_1d` with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) and [repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
def f(x):
    return x * x
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b= numpy.vectorize(f)(a)
c = numpy.repeat(b.reshape( (-1,1) ),2, axis=1)
print c
```

output:

```
[[1 1]
 [4 4]
 [9 9]]
```

You can also just set the array.shape tuple directly.
It may be worthwhile to know that you can accomplish the same as `vectorize` using `map`, **if** you ever need to write pure python. `b= numpy.vectorize(f)(a)` would become `b=map(f,a)`

Using this kind of approach, it becomes unnecessary to have your `f_1d` at all, since all it seems to do is duplicate information, which is done best by `numpy.repeat`.

Also, this version is a bit faster, but this only matters if you're dealing with large arrays.

Comment: Hmmm either my question wasn't clear enough, or there is something I don't understand. I just added an example to my question, please update your answer if possible.

Comment: @c00kiemonster Indeed, I misunderstood your question slighly, your example makes it clearer. I've edited my answer